# Can search find files within unexpanded folders in Netbeans projects sidebar?

Tags: php, netbeans

In the Projects sidebar of Netbeans, when you start typing letters a partial name match is done on files being displayed the sidebar (a sort of quickfind just by typing, not the ctrl+f find dialog box). As my project is contained over various sub-folders, most are unexpanded which means the partial name match search doesn't pick up files in those folders.

Is it possible to have this search include unexpanded folders? Unless you always have all folders expanded, this facility doesn't seem very useful otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

That would be a very expensive operation. No it is not currently possible. You can try the "Find in Files" search instead.